# 'with' keyword usage in scala with case classes

Tags: scala, types, case-class

I though if something like this makes sense in scala:

```
object CaseClassUnion extends App {
  case class HttpConfig(bindUrl: String, port: String)
  case class DbConfig(url: String, usr: String, pass: String)

  val combined: HttpConfig with DbConfig = ???
  
  //HttpConfig("0.0.0.0", "21") ++ DbConfig("localhost", "root", "root") 
  //would be nice to have something like that
}
```

At least this compiles... Is there a way, probably with macros magic to achieve union of two classes given their instances?
In **zio** I believe there is something like in reverse:

```
val live: ZLayer[ProfileConfiguration with Logging, Nothing, ApplicationConfiguration] =
ZLayer.fromServices[ProfileConfigurationModule.Service, Logger[String], Service] { (profileConfig, logger) =>  ???
```

where we convert `ProfileConfiguration with Logging` to function of `ProfileConfigurationModule.Service, Logger[String] => Service`

Comment: You must NOT extend case classes, and they [should be final](https://nrinaudo.github.io/scala-best-practices/tricky_behaviours/final_case_classes.html) - What you want to do is have two traits defining all the interfaces and then you create a single case class that extends both traits. - You can not magically mix two values to get an intersection type, you may also just use a tuple.

Comment: Vanilla Scala doesn't support product of two case classes. You can use `HList` for those two types and then the product type will be something like `val combined: HttpConfig :: DbConfig :: HNil = httpConfig :: dbConfig:: HNil`. If you wish to use vanilla Scala, you will have to do the boilerplate yourself and define a new case class.

Comment: @texasbruce, `(HttpConfig, DbConfig)` is a product of two case classes... (whether using a tuple is a good idea is a different matter entirely)

Comment: @LeviRamsey I meant product of two case classes into a single case class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things.

When you have several `trait`s combined with `with` Scala does a trait linearization to combine them into one class with a linear hierarchy. But that's true for `trait`s which doesn't have constructors!

`case class` (which is not a trait) cannot be extended with another `case class` (at all) because that would break contracts like:

```
case class A(a: Int)
case class B(a: Int, b: String) extends A(a)

A(1) == B(1, "") // because B is A and their respective fields match
B(1, "") != A(1) // because A is not B
B(1, "").hashCode != A(1).hashCode // A == B is true but hashCodes are different!
```

which means that you cannot even generate `case class` combination manually. You want to "combine" them, use some product: a tuple, another case class, etc.

If you are curious about ZIO it:

- uses traits
- uses them as some sort of type-level trick to represent an unordered set of dependencies, where type inference would calculate set sum when you combine operations and some clever trickery to remove traits from the list using `.provide` to remove dependency from the set
- ZLayers are just making these shenanigans easier

so and if you even pass there some `A with B` you either combined it yourself by using cake pattern, or you passed dependencies one by one. ZIO developer might never be faced with the problem of needing some macro to combine several case classes (`.provide(combineMagically(A, B, C, D, ...)`) as they could pass implementations of each dependency one by one (`.provide(A).provide(B)`) and the code underneath would never need the combination of these types as one value - it's just a compile-time trick that might never translate to the requirement of an actual value of type `A with B with C with D ...`.

TL;DR: You cannot generate a combination of 2 case classes; ZIO uses compound types as some sort of type-level set to trace dependencies and it doesn't actually require creating values of the compound types.